# Android Emulator crashing on host machine when RDPing from another machine

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization, remote-desktop

I've got a rdp connection setup between my pc in work and my pc at home. My home pc has an android emulator setup and works fine when I'm working on my home pc but crashes when I rdp to it and launch it. I get the following crash report:

[image]

I haven't been able to find much useful information so far, so has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a weird work around whereby I launched the emulator from Visual Studio which worked fine and then I could deploy my apps from whatever software I want e.g. Visual studio code, Android studio etc